# How to add mulitple ActionMap for a JButton in Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have an JButton placed inside a JPanel .Now I have added a key Listener to this button via AbstractAction . But what i want is :  say I have assigned the keyboard key 'A' to this button . Now when i press the key 'A' i want to show that the button is pressed on GUI . I tried using Jbutton.setEnabled() .But that doesn’t work since i have to enable & disbale the button . And i guess the action inside the AbstractAction gets executed at the end and not in the middle. I have posted my code below:

```
private Action buttonPressed(final JButton jButton,final Boolean black) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

    AbstractAction buttonPressed = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int index=keys_names.indexOf(e.getActionCommand().toUpperCase());
            if(index>=0)
            {

                jButton.setEnabled(false);
                // DO some other action

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                jButton.setEnabled(true);



            }

        }
    };
    return buttonPressed;
}
```

and the JButton used is :

```
JButton b1=new JButton();
b1.getInputMap(javax.swing.JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A,0), keys_names.get(key_press));
b1.getActionMap().put(keys_names.get(key_press),buttonPressed(b1,false));
```

Comment: A button can only have a single `ActionMap`, but it may have multiple `Action`s within the map...

Comment: Have you tried calling `doClick` on the button?  Have you tried changing the button's model state?

Comment: Okay . Is there any way by which I can show that the key press is related to button by disabling & enabling the button ?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply call `JButton#doClick` which should mimic the button been pressed, visually as well as calling the buttons `ActionListener`s.  But you want to really highlight the fact, you could use `JButton#doClick(int)` which will allow you to pass the amount of time the button should "appear" pressed

For example...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestButton {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestButton();
    }

    public TestButton() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JButton b1 = new JButton("Click Me");
                b1.getInputMap(javax.swing.JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0), "bang");
                b1.getActionMap().put("bang", new ClickMeAction());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(b1);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ClickMeAction extends AbstractAction {

        public ClickMeAction() {
            putValue(NAME, "Click me");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
            btn.doClick(1000);
        }

    }

}
```